# How to implement sync communication when Server site handles request asynchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous

How to implement sync communication when Server site handle request asynchronously?

I mean how client site handle this communication model?

Similar communication handled in XMPP messaging protocol when sending IQ message.

IQ message is handled at backend site asynchronously, in other words when request comes into server it is quesued to be processed , after that response is send back from available channels.

Client site waits for response as if communication was like http-rest call

Comment: For client, there is no difference whether server works synchronously or asynchronously. Client simply sends requests and receives replies. Any server sends reply strictly after receiving request, that is, all servers behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into **DeferredResult** or the new java 8 **CompletableFuture**.

The code would look something like this in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<String> getAsyncTest() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processReq);
}

private String processReq() {
    log.info("Dummy work");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "test";
}
```

Here is a good read on this topic: https://nickebbitt.github.io/blog/2017/03/22/async-web-service-using-completable-future

**[Client side example]**
You could use RXJS with Observables:

```
getTest().subscribe((response) => {
        // Do something on success
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

getTest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<>('/test');
}
```

Comment: this is for server site implementation, I need client site, when I checked TEST cases it works as usual, sync method call

Comment: I made an update with a client side example (Angular 6+). You can use Promises or Observables depending on your client impl.

Comment: If this is not what you mean, maybe you can share some more info. (some code snippets)